# SET IDENTITY_INSERT postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not familiar with postgresql script.

I already use this script in ms sql server :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT my_table ON
INSERT INTO my_table (
  my_identity_field,
  field1,
  field2
) 
SELECT 
  fieldA,
  fieldB
FROM
  my_other_table
WHERE
  fieldC = some_value
SET IDENTITY_INSERT my_table OFF
```

Question :
What is the script 'SET IDENTIFY_INSERT [table_name] ON/OFF' in PostgreSQL ?

Thank you

**SOLVED :**

```
INSERT INTO my_table (
  my_identity_field,
  field1,
  field2
) 
SELECT 
  fieldA,
  fieldB
FROM
  my_other_table
WHERE
  fieldC = some_value;

SELECT 
setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table', 'my_identity_field'), 
(SELECT MAX(my_identity_field) FROM my_table));
```

**Note:**
'my_table' and 'my_identity_field' in lowercase
I'm getting error if they're not in lowercase (all letters)

Comment: Do you mean you want the equivalent syntax of `SET IDENTIFY_INSERT [table_name] ON/OFF` in Postgresql

Comment: **Yes**, can i get oneline script ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't need `set identity_insert` in Postgres.

Just insert the data into your table.

What you need to do however, is to re-sync the sequences that's behind your serial ("auto increment") column using the `setval()` function:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table', 'my_serial_column'), 
              (select max(my_serial_column) from my_table) 
       );
```

If the column is not defined as a `serial` but "only" has a default value taken from a sequence, you need to supply the sequence name "manually"

```
select setval('my_sequence_name', (select max(my_serial_column) 
                                   from my_table)
       );
```

**Edit**

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/690ea/1

Comment: So, I just need this ? 

`    INSERT INTO my_table (
      field1,
      field2
    ) 
    SELECT 
      fieldA,
      fieldB
    FROM
      my_other_table
    WHERE
      fieldC = some_value`

Then : 

    `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence(my_table,my_serial_field,(SELECT MAX(my_serial_field) FROM my_table`

Comment: @user3239588: yes - but you need to put the table and column names in single quotes in the call to `pg_get_serial_sequence` the way I did it in my example

Comment: like this ? `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table','my_serial_field',(SELECT MAX('my_serial_field') FROM my_table`

Comment: @user3239588: yes, see the SQLFiddle.