# Auto generate ID in massive PostgreSQL INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to copy a table into another, but the fields are not the same (it is not a problem), and some fields in table destination are optional.

I do somethink like this:

```
INSERT INTO data(Email, Title, FirstName, LastName) 
SELECT champs5, champs1, champs3, champs4 
FROM tmp
```

But the problem comes from the id field who is of course required:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I tell to Postgres to auto generate the ID for each line of the `INSERT`?

Comment: Please post the `create table` statement for the table `data` (my guess is: you didn't specify `id` as `serial`). See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html

Comment: Seems like this maybe close to what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375651/set-identity-insert-postgresql

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, your right, my id field was a bigint without the nextval('data_id2_seq'::regclass) of the default value serial.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Your comment is the answer.