# Insert coulmns of 1 table into multiple tables as row all having same ID

Tags: postgresql

I need to insert data from one table into three different tables (see example below):

### before

```
source_table:    
id row_1 row_2 row_3
```

### after

```
table_1:
obj_id row_1

table_2:
obj_id row_2

table_3:
obj_id row_3
```

table_1, table_2 and table_3 have the same obj_id (type serial).

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: use triggers in postgresql, AFTER INSERT

Comment: Do you really have _columns_ that are named `row_1`?

Comment: No it is an example..

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat the code bellow for each of the tables:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (id, row_1)
SELECT id, row_1
FROM source_table
```

If you have serial ("auto increment") column, look at this answer: [SET IDENTITY_INSERT postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375651/set-identity-insert-postgresql?answertab=votes#tab-top)

In SQL Server, you need to set identity_insert on first and turn it off at the end.

Comment: Indeed I do have a serial obj_id. The id in the source table isn't the same as the one in the arrival tables.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how to use Identity_insert in my case? What I need is to have the same obj_id in table_1, table_2 and table_3