# C# how to execute a npsql command on a data base in a context file insted of using _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand for SQL

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a C# project that uses two providers : SQL and POSTGRESS.

I have to run a command on the DB to turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON and OFF.

I know how to do it in SQL :

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].CustomerType ON");
```

But , how do I do the same thing with POSTGRESS  ?

What I thought is :

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].CustomerType ON");
```

But I am  not sure this is the way to do this .

These are my line code :

```
var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
                            strategy.Execute(() =>
                            {
                                using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                                {
                                    bool isIsNpgsql = _context.Database.IsNpgsql();

                                    _context.CustomerType.Add(ManagementCustomerType);
                                    if (isIsNpgsql)
                                    {
                                       
                                        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].CustomerType ON");
                                        _context.SaveChanges();
                                        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].CustomerType OFF");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].CustomerType ON");
                                            _context.SaveChanges();
                                            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].CustomerType OFF");
                                    }
                                    transaction.Commit();
                                }
                            });
```

All help will be appraised !

Comment: Just insert your Data. All you need is Sequences. Check this link for more detailed info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375651/set-identity-insert-postgresql

Comment: Thanks!
You directed me in the right direction!